# Firebase Unknown Property Exception

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying to learn about Firebase and in my first example there's an error that I simply don't understand. If anybody can help me I would be so thankful

THIS IS MY MAINACTIVITY.JAVA

```
package com.example.betterlaylow.firebasetestinsertretrieve;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText editTextName;
private EditText editTextAddress;
private TextView textViewPersons;
private Button buttonSave;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

    buttonSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    editTextAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddress);

    textViewPersons = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPersons);

    //Click Listener for button
    buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Creating firebase object
            Firebase ref = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL);

            //Getting values to store
            String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
            String address = editTextAddress.getText().toString().trim();

            //Creating Person object
            Person person = new Person();

            //Adding values
            person.setName(name);
            person.setAddress(address);

            //Storing values to firebase
            ref.child("Person").setValue(person);


            //Value event listener for realtime data update
            ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        //Getting the data from snapshot
                        Person person = postSnapshot.getValue(Person.class);

                        //Adding it to a string
                        String string = "Name: "+person.getName()+"\nAddress: "+person.getAddress()+"\n\n";

                        //Displaying it on textview
                        textViewPersons.setText(string);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                    System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
                }
            });

        }
    });
}

}
```

THIS IS MY PERSON.JAVA

```
package com.example.betterlaylow.firebasetestinsertretrieve;

/**
 * Created by betterlaylow on 7/26/16.
 */

public class Person {
//name and address string
private String name;
private String address;

public Person() {
  /*Blank default constructor essential for Firebase*/
}
//Getters and setters
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
}
```

THIS IS MY CONFIG.JAVA

```
package com.example.betterlaylow.firebasetestinsertretrieve;

/**
 * Created by betterlaylow on 7/26/16.
 */
 public class Config {
public static final String FIREBASE_URL = "https://simplifiedcoding.firebaseio.com/";


}
```

AND THIS ID THE ANDROID MONITOR

07-26 21:07:06.917 6408-6408/com.example.betterlaylow.firebasetestinsertretrieve E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                   Process: com.example.betterlaylow.firebasetestinsertretrieve, PID: 6408
                                                                                                   com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type
                                                                                                       at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:185)
                                                                                                       at com.example.betterlaylow.firebasetestinsertretrieve.MainActivity$1$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:66)
                                                                                                       at com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:45)
                                                                                                       at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45)
                                                                                                       at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38)
                                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                                    Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "msg" (class com.example.betterlaylow.firebasetestinsertretrieve.Person), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: , "address", "name"])
                                                                                                       at [Source: java.io.StringReader@f02156a; line: 1, column: 9] (through reference chain: com.example.betterlaylow.firebasetestinsertretrieve.Person["msg"])
                                                                                                       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:555)
                                                                                                       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:708)
                                                                                                       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1160)
                                                                                                       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:315)
                                                                                                       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:121)
                                                                                                       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2888)
                                                                                                       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2034)
                                                                                                       at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:183)
                                                                                                       at com.example.betterlaylow.firebasetestinsertretrieve.MainActivity$1$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:66) 
                                                                                                       at com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:45) 
                                                                                                       at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45) 
                                                                                                       at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38) 
                                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Answer (score 0):

You have coded your listener to expect that there are multiple instances of `Person` under location "Person".  To do that you need to create a unique key for each person created using the [push()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#push()) method of `DatabaseReference`:

```
        //Storing values to firebase
        ref.child("Person").push().setValue(person);
```

Alternatively, if you only want one `Person` at location "Person" change the listener like this:

```
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    Person person = snapshot.getValue(Person.class);

                    //Adding it to a string
                    String string = "Name: "+person.getName()+"\nAddress: "+person.getAddress()+"\n\n";

                    //Displaying it on textview
                    textViewPersons.setText(string);

            }
```

Also, the Firebase SDK you are using is not the current one.  If you are just getting started with Firebase, why not use [the latest](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/)?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing ***@IgnoreExtraProperties*** from your class.
Write your POJO class something like this:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Person {

private String name;
private String address;

public Person() {
  /*Blank default constructor essential for Firebase*/
}
//Getters and setters
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
}
```